# What does Pinterest uses for CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm currently cloning Pinterest's website with React and styled-components to study. But I'm intrigued with what they use for CSS, since each class name is reused a bunch of times. For an example:

```
<div class="Jea gjz xcv L4E zI7 iyn Hsu" />
```

CSS:

```
.gjz {
  align-items: center;
},

.Jea{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Both classes seem to be auto-generated and are reused throughout the whole site. Is there a specific CSS framework that does that, or is this plain CSS with something else?

Comment: Pure guess, but Tailwind CSS minified could possibly look like that.

Comment: If you look around enough, you will see this sort of pattern in tons of places. It's really just a form of obfuscation, intended to make "reverse engineering" stylesheets harder.